# Show that $\mathbb{P}(R\leq r, \phi \leq \varphi) = \mathbb{P}(R\leq r)\cdot \mathbb{P}(\phi\leq \varphi)$

Tags: probability-distributions, independence

Be $X=(X_1,X_2)$ a uniform distribution on the unit circle.

We can rewrite $X$ as polar coordinates $R=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$, $\Phi=\arctan(X_2/X_1)$

Show that $R, \Phi$ are independent.

---

In my book, I can see that $R, \Phi$ are independent, if $\mathbb{P}(R\leq r, \phi \leq \varphi) = \mathbb{P}(R\leq r)\cdot \mathbb{P}(\phi\leq \varphi)$

The proof in the book is short: $\mathbb{P}(R\leq r, \phi \leq \varphi) = \varphi \frac{r^2}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\pi}=\underbrace{\mathbb{P}(R\leq r)}_{r^2}\cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(\phi\leq \varphi)}_{\varphi/(2\pi)}$

I get why $\mathbb{P}(\phi\leq \varphi)= \frac{\lambda_2(K_r\cap K_1)}{\lambda_2(K_1)}=(r^2\pi)/\pi = r^2$

(Where $\lambda_2$ is the Lebesgue-measure, $K_1$ is the unit circle and $K_r$ is the circle with radius $r$)

But I don't get why $\mathbb{P}(R\leq r, \phi \leq \varphi) = \varphi \frac{r^2}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\pi}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\phi\leq \varphi)=\varphi/(2\pi)$.

Could someone please explain this to me in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\phi \le \varphi)$ is the probability that $X$ lies in a sector of the unit circle subtended by angle $\varphi$. The area of this "pizza slice" is $\frac{\varphi}{2\pi} \cdot \pi$. Because $X$ is uniform on the unit circle, the probability is $$\frac{\text{area of sector}}{\text{area of unit circle}} = \frac{\frac{\varphi}{2\pi} \cdot \pi}{\pi} = \frac{\varphi}{2\pi}. $$

$P(R \le r, \phi \le \varphi)$ is the probability that $X$ is in a sector of a circle of radius $r$ subtended by an angle $\varphi$. (It may help to draw a picture.) Because $X$ is uniform on the unit circle, the probability that $X$ is in this sector is $$\frac{\text{area of sector}}{\text{area of unit circle}} = \frac{\frac{\varphi}{2\pi}\cdot\pi r^2}{\pi} = \varphi \frac{r^2}{2} \frac{1}{\pi}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Imagine breaking the unit circle into many smaller areas. Because our distribution is uniform, the probability of our random point being in any given region is equal to its area divided by the total area of the circle. So, as the size of the slices get large, the probability of being in any given area approaches $\frac{dA}{\pi}.$

So to get the probability of our chosen section, we can integrate to add up the probabilities of being in each of those smaller sections. So, our probability is equal to:

$$\iint_D \frac{dA}{\pi} = \int_0^{\varphi}\int_0^r \frac{R dR d\theta}{\pi}=\frac{r^2}{2\pi} \int_0^{\varphi} d \theta = \frac{\varphi r^2}{2\pi}$$