# $R^2$ and $\Phi/(2\pi)$ are independent and uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-distributions, independence

Be $X=(X_1,X_2)$ a uniform distribution on the unit circle.

We can rewrite $X$ as polar coordinates $R=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$, $\Phi=\arctan(X_2/X_1)$

With some help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106180/show-that-mathbbpr-leq-r-phi-leq-varphi-mathbbpr-leq-r-cdot-ma/4106198#4106198), I know know that $R, \Phi$ are independent. I was asked to show from that result, that $A_1=R^2$ and $A_2=\Phi/(2\pi)$ are independent and continuous uniform in $(0,1)$

But what exactly do I need to show? I know that $X_1 = \sqrt{A_1}\cos(2\pi A_2)$ and $X_2 = \sqrt{A_2}\sin(2\pi A_2)$ from the definition of polar coordinates. Can't I just say: $R$ independent in $(0,1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $R^2$ independent in $(0,1^2)=(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independence of $R$ and $\Phi$ implies independence of $f(R)$ and $g(\Phi)$ for any measurable  functions $f$ and $g$. This gives the independence of $R^{2}$ and $\frac {\Phi} {2\pi}$.

$P(R^{2}\leq r)=P(X_1^{2}+X_2^{2}\leq r)= \frac  A {\pi }$ where $A$ is the areas of the circle of radius $\sqrt r$. Since $A=\pi r$ we get $P(R^{2}\leq r)= r$.  Hence $R^{2}$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Similarly you can use the formula for the area of a   sector of the circle to prove that $\frac {\Phi} {2\pi}$ also has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Comment: For $P(\Phi /(2\pi)\leq \varphi) = P(\Phi \leq 2\pi \varphi) = \frac{\frac{2\pi \varphi}{2\pi} \pi}{\pi} =  \varphi$. I understand the process but I'm not sure if I understand why this shows uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

Comment: That is the.  definition of uniform distribution. If $P(X\leq t)=t$ for $0<t<1$ then $X$ has uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.@Quotenbanane

Comment: Ohh. Thanks, very good explanation.